# How do I make the "show/hide desktop icons" setting take effect?

Tags: delphi, winapi, shell

The code below calls SHGetSetSettings function to hide desktop icons
but it just unchecked  "Show desktop icons" from the view menu.

I called `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, nil, nil);` 
to update the desktop but that doesn't work?

```
var
lpss: SHELLSTATE;
begin
  lpss.Data := High(cardinal);
  lpss.Data2 := Low(cardinal);
  SHGetSetSettings(lpss,SSF_HIDEICONS,true);
  SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, nil, nil);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

isa, to refresh the desktop you can send the F5  key to the `progman` (Program Manager) window

```
PostMessage(FindWindow('Progman', nil), WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 3);
```

another alternative to hide the desktop icons is

```
ShowWindow(FindWindow('Progman', nil),SW_HIDE); //hide the icons desktop and refresh the screen
```

to show again

```
ShowWindow(FindWindow('Progman', nil),SW_SHOW); //show the icons of the desktop and refresh
```

Comment: hiding the 'Progman' will disable right-click on the desktop.

sending f5 to desktop doesn't work too.

Comment: @isa, i've tried sending the F5 key and works ok for me. wich version of windows are you using?

Comment: sending the F5 key to refresh the desktop works, i meant it doesn't hide the icons after caling  
SHGetSetSettings(lpss,SSF_HIDEICONS,true);

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer since I don't know why `SHGetSetSettings` does not work. However you can do what the shell does to hide the icons; hide the *List-View* control.

This is the window hiearchy of the desktop;

```
'Program Manager' - Progman
  '' - SHELLDLL_DefView
    'FolderView' - SysListView32
```

The 'SysListView32' is the one displaying the icons.

You can test and see if the shell is indeed hiding the list-view; hide the icons with the "show desktop icons" item in the view menu, then run the below,

```
function GetDesktopListView: HWnd;
begin
  Result := GetWindow(GetWindow(FindWindow('Progman', nil), GW_CHILD), GW_CHILD);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(GetDesktopListView, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

and the icons will show again.

Since you're able to check/uncheck the menu item by using 'SHGetSetSettings', the icons' visibility would be -**seemingly**- in accordance. Also, you don't need to refresh the desktop since the visibility change would take effect immediately.

Comment: Since this answer is already presented as a workaround to the *correct* approach, which for some reason or another does not work, I'd like to be advised about the reason of the down-vote.

Comment: @Altar - Maybe you have background picture rotation active, I don't know it's name - that's your background picture changes after a specified period. If that's the case this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4521957) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, don't you think that SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED is a wrong choice?

SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED says "file association was changed". You didn't change any *file association*. You've changed *Shell settings*. See the difference?

Try SHCNE_ALLEVENTS instead (I would also try SHCNE_UPDATEDIR and SHCNE_UPDATEITEM with Desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried broadcasting [WM_SETTINGCHANGE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: Yes.  It has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

To hide or show the desktop icons:

```
Procedure DesktopIcons(Const Show : Boolean);
 Var
   h : HWND;
 begin
   h := GetWindow(FindWindow('Progman', 'Program Manager'), GW_CHILD);
   If Show then ShowWindow(h, SW_SHOW)
    else ShowWindow(h, SW_HIDE);
end;
```