# Toggle show/hide system files from Delphi

Tags: delphi, file, toggle, hidden

Is there any built-in Delphi function to toggle between show and hide system files (protected operating system files) under Windows? Or maybe a registry entry in HKCU? Or maybe an API function able to do this?

I don't ask for a trick to show/hide this kind of files in my application, I need something to work even for Windows Explorer.

Operating systems : Win XP SP1+, Vista, 7

I don't mind even if I have to pass over an UAC notification.

Comment: by using SHGetSetSettings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RBA, but only for Windows from `Windows XP` to `Windows XP with SP2`, what is quite narrow range of versions.

Comment: @TLama - indeed. Op, which is the operating system version?

Comment: based on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484860/calling-shgetsetsettings-from-delphi - you need to set the fShowSysFiles member. at this moment I do not have a Delphi at hand, but it should not be difficult. noroc

Comment: This is a user setting that programs are not meant to alter. Now, if your program provides an alternative UI for modifications to shell settings then that seems reasonable. If you change this shell setting without the user's explicit permission, you are writing malware.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - you are correct. But, if this is demanded by the client, or has learning purposes I do not see any problem.

Comment: @RBA If the program changes the setting silently, it is malware.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I'm sure that the op does not intend something like this. do you op? ;)

Comment: @RBA Buiding an app and working under HKCU is a sign that the product is a malware? I would preffer HKLM for a malware app.

Comment: @IulianStoian foloseste frate HKCU oricum daca aplicatia nu e semnata digital tot se gaseste un antivirus sa te marcheze ca suspicios

Comment: ok, I'll wait a while, and then probably i'll choose opc0de asnwer as the accepted answer. Thanks all for your interest.

Comment: @IulianStoian - that depends on multiple factors. you should notify the user about all the actions your application is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is a gross hack use it on your own risk

User Key: [`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`]

Value Name: ShowSuperHidden

Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)

Value Data: (1 = show hidden, 2 = do not show)

This registry value enables you to show or hide the system files.Thus those files with the attribute hidden

Comment: Settings should not be modified by hacking the registry. Instead the official API should be used. Now, that official API may in turn implement the setting persistence via the registry, but that's implementation detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if we all sticked to rules the software will never be what is today.And I don't think is any API for this

Comment: But you haven't mentioned any of that in your answer. You should state clearly that this is a gross hack and is against all recommended best practice. Then if the user still wants to do it, at least you warned.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan better now ? ;)

Comment: One small rectification: Key Value Name is ShowSuperHidden, not Hidden. Seems like Hidden value name is for files marked with Hidden attribute, not the System ones.