# Calling SHGetSetSettings from Delphi XE returns nothing

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe

What I try to do is to hide the desktopicons. 
I have a hack that works but I want to do it the proper way, using SHGetSetSettings.
The thing is that after calling SHGetSetSettings, the record is filled with zeros!

```
procedure GetDesktopData;
var
  lpss: tagSHELLSTATEW;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lpss, SizeOf(lpss));
  SHGetSetSettings(lpss, SSF_HIDEICONS, FALSE); { TRUE to indicate that the contents of lpss should be used to set the Shell settings, FALSE to indicate that the Shell settings should be retrieved to lpss. }
end;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the record was not filled with data?
I have Windows 7.

---

This question is similar to this one [Calling SHGetSetSettings from Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484860/calling-shgetsetsettings-from-delphi), but not identical. That question discusses the structure for calling SHGetSetSettings from Delphi 2010. The function and the afferent structure is now present under Delphi xE (but still not working).

---

Solution provided by TLama.

Comment: From the note "*SHGetSetSettings is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section.* ***It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions***" I wouldn't feel confident...

Comment: Oh, damn it: "End of client support - Windows XP with SP2"

Comment: @TLama-You can already post your comment as an answer so I can accept it